# What's wrong with this regex on PostgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Can anyone explain to me why this regex select returns false in PostgreSQL:

```
select '354902050487064_Gismo3' ~* '\d{15}_\w+'
```

Tried it on several online regex testers and in matches fine.

Thanks

Comment: Returns `true` for me in 9.4

Comment: It returns true on my 9.4.0 (windows) and 9.3.4 (Linux) installation

Comment: Ok, got it. In SQL the \ char has to be doubbled, so this expression works: `select '354902050487064_Gismo3' ~* '\\d{15}_\\w+'` I'm on 6.0.7 64-bit. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Correction: I'm on 9.0.7 64-bit of course.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslashes:

```
select '354902050487064_Gismo3' ~* '\\d{15}_\\w+'
```

Comment: Yes, just found that out and added at comment, but thanks anyway.